# Decode xml captions file

Tags: video.js

I have an online movie web. I use videojs to play video and set captions as subtitle. But its weekness is that someone will easyly stoles the subtitle file. As the code is:

```
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="700" height="420" poster="http://i.imgur.com/wiXKfA1.png" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="videos/338.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <track src='subs/338.vtt' srclang='vi' label='Viet-sub' default></track>
            <track src="subs/338eng.vtt" srclang="eng" label="Eng-sub"></track>
            <track kind="captions" src="subs/338.vtt" srclang="vi" label="Vi"></track>
</video>
```

They just need to viesource and get the vtt file.

I don't want someone stoles the subtitle file, so that I want to use xml file to describe this subtitle. The xml file is as this link: http://naruto.crazy-sub.com/input.xml

How can I use this xml file instead of the vtt file for my videos? Anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: How will using an XML file be any more secure?

Comment: Because they can't decode xml file to get the content of subtitle anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...XML is plaintext and could easily be read in the same way a WebVTT file could.